# AJAX requests inside loop: aborting certain ajax call based on the response of the previous call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, event-loop

I have an array of 'projects' containing the project owner id, and the project's title.

I want to get each project's owner name by looping through the 'projects' array, and making a request call, passing each project 'owner id', to some server using AJAX.

```
var projects = [
     {owner_id: 1, title: "First project by id one"},
     {owner_id: 2, title: "First project by id two"},
     {owner_id: 1, title: "Second project by id one"},
     {owner_id: 3, title: "First project by id three"}
];

//iterate through the 'projects' array to get the project's owner_id its respective owner_name
var owner_names = {};
projects.forEach(function(project) {
     //check if the id exist in the owner_names key-value pair
     if (project.owner_id in owner_names) {
         //go the next iteration because we already know the owner name
         return;
     }

     //get username by id
     $.ajax({
         url: '//some.com/get/owner_name/by/id/',
         data: project.owner_id
     }.then(function(data) {
         owner_names[data.id] = data.name;
         console.log("First project by " + data.name + " is " +  project.title);
     });


});
```

I want to abort / not calling the ajax function when the project iteration is the "Second project by id one" because I would have gotten the data when the iteration was "First project by id one".

That is to say, **I want to output this** (assume owner_id 1,2,3, is Alice, Bob and Charlie respectively):

```
First project by Alice is First project by id one 
First project by Bob is First project by id two
First project by Charlie is First project by id three
```

**But instead, I got this**:

```
First project by Alice is First project by id one
First project by Bob is First project by id two
First project by Alice is Second project by id one  
First project by Charlie is First project by id three
```

How could I achieve this while maintaining the asynchronousity (without using "async=false") in AJAX?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [`Promise.race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race). However, to do what you're asking, you'll need to group up the data by owner ID first and pass them to `Promise.race`. Do this for every owner that has multiple projects.

```
// Something like...
Promise.all([
  Promise.race([ owner1project1ajax, owner1project2ajax ]),
  owner2project1ajax,
  owner3project1ajax,
])
```

Note that while `$.when` is the jQuery equivalent for `Promise.all`, there is no jQuery equivalent for `Promise.race`. Also it won't abort the other promises, but will resolve with the value of the promise that resolves/rejects first, ignoring the rest.